# Command to Reset the Bytes Sent/Received counters on Windows Network Interface Status

Tags: windows, networking, traffic

Is there a command in Windows (XP or 7) to zero the byte counters on a network Interface, without disabling and enabling the interface, or disconnecting and reconnecting?

Comment: Perhaps disabling and re-enabling the interface will do it. If so netsh or devcon should do the trick.

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing that. I have edited the question. Thanks.